# libinput-gestures on wayland: can't get 'super' key

Tags: linux, input, multi-touch, gnome, trackpad

I'm trying to configure libinput-gestures by editing `/etc/libinput-gestures.conf`.

I'm using gnome 3.28.1 on Linux Mint 19 and I want to trigger 'activities overview' with a given multi-touch trackpad gesture.

Libinput-gestures is working for switching desktops using

`_internal ws_up` &

`_internal ws_down` in the config file.

The way I got into overview in Linux Mint 18.03 is by sending a key via

`xdotool key super` for 'activities overview' &

`xdotool key super+a` for 'show applications'.

From my research I have found that the version of gnome I had in mint 18 used x11 as it's display manager and the version of gnome in mint 19 uses wayland.  Wayland has I believe deprecated the ability to 'send keys' for security reasons.

Solutions to this problem might be:

- A way to trigger the 'activities overview' from the terminal.
- A way around waylands blocking of 'send key'.

All insights are appreciated.
Thanks :)

Comment: I'm trying to do the exact same thing.  Have you found a solution?  I was just using x-window for a while and I'm wanting to switch to wayland.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post.  However, I've also been looking for a solution in using different gestures in Wayland.  There's an example of the op's post right in the libinput-gestures.conf file.

```
gesture swipe up 3 dbus-send --session --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.Shell /org/gnome/Shell org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.overview.toggle();'
```

This is effectively the equivalence of pressing the Super_L key.
What I'd like to know is if there's a similar command for "Show Applications" that might be compatible with Wayland.  What other possibilities using "dbus" are there?  I've researched for days and have found little information on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way would be to have `gjs` call `Main.overview.toggle()` though I'm on mobile right now, so I don't have access to it.

I'll edit this in the next hour or so for a complete answer, when I can confirm the exact syntax